# running only one program of a vm

Tags: windows, vmware

I'm using Ubuntu as  a main machine and win 10 as virtual machine is there any way to run only one app of the VM and not the entire VM to save resources and battery

Comment: VMWare will take the resources regardless of what is running inside of it.  Look into maybe running the one app in Wine where it is not taking up all the resources until the application itself is ran.

Comment: @Terrance: That sounds almost like an answer. :-]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to clarify what the application in question is and/or does? Maybe we can point you to better alternatives with this information. Thanks.